# Query on the socket() function

Tags: c, sockets

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

Am I correct in my understanding that this will utilise a local port for this socket, and can anyone clarify which port it decides to use? Is there a way to control which local port the socket is opened on?

Comment: Please read `man socket`.

Comment: Again such a case, where the questioner seems to have decided that it might be less effort letting others tell her/him the answer to what s/he wants know then doing own researches. The questions assumption simply are wrong, from what one can draw the conclusion no prior research was done at all.

Comment: @alk What was the point of that post other than to solicit some points off you peers? Enough people answered the question and didn't mind it, I guess that means that you are just 'that guy'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will just create an AF_INET (ipv4) socket that does TCP. Once you call `connect` it will bind to a port, if not already done so via `bind`. If you want to pick a port number yourself, just `bind` manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) to control which local port you use.  You can optionally also use it to choose which network interface to use.

The following code selects port 12345 on all available interfaces

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = 2;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.in_port = htons(12345);
int err = bind(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

If you don't care which port you use, port 0 is treated as a special case where the network stack chooses an(y) available port

Comment: So it does use a local port, and if the server is not allowing ports to be used in a certain range, it seeks a free port?

Comment: @user1166981 The receiving side of the socket (call it a server if you want) has nothing to do with the local port logic. By the time the receiving side gets a SYN frame it already has a port number assigned on both ends.

Answer (score 1):

The freshly created socket does not have an address until you `bind()`, `listen()`, or `connect()` it.

If you want to `connect()` or `listen()` on that socket, you don't necessarily have to bind to an address and port first; one will be automatically assigned.  However, if you're trying to run a server that others will connect to you will probably want to first `bind()` to a known address and port.  Sometimes you want to connect out from a particular address and port, and you here you also have to `bind()` first.

If you want to find the address to which an existing socket is bound, use `getsockname()`.

Answer (score 0):

Read [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and and [ip(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) man pages and some [tutorial on Linux sockets](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html). You also need to call the [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) syscall to bind to some particular port.